# BASE24 tutorial or learning material

Tags: c, cobol

Does someone know where I can find a tutorial or material relating to Base24? I'm referring to Base24 the product by [ACI](http://www.aciworldwide.com/). My understanding is that they use a programming language called 'TAL' which has similarities to Cobol and C.

I've searched the net and I have only found job opportunities for Base24 developers but hardly any learning resources.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TAL stands for "Transaction Application Language" and is supported by HP.

There's a programmer's guide [here](http://docs.hp.com/en/096254/096254.pdf) and a reference manual [here](http://docs.hp.com/en/526371-001/526371-001.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I googled for **base24 programming** and the second hit was this http://2020ok.com/books/13/a-guide-to-using-aci-worldwide-s-base24-es-on-z-os-34513.htm